# Is there an application to create xml or plist files in a visual way?

Tags: applications, data, xml

**What do I mean by "in a visual way" ?**

Actually, I would like to create a simple "structure" where an element can have several sons, and so on. The `xml` format is a good format for this structure. But, the `plist` format could also do it.

I am looking for a software that would allow me to create the structure with the help of a good interface :

- viewing it as a tree
- maybe moving/copying branches, etc.

---

EDIT : So far, I am using Xcode. I am looking for a more "graphical" editor.

Comment: Also see in [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1609112/is-there-an-xml-editor-with-grid-view-similar-to-that-of-xmlspy/16429171#16429171)

Comment: The only difference is that this question _also_ specifically asks about .plist format. Of course it's a type of XML file… does that mean _all_ XML editors that work on OS X can open .plist files? If they can open them can they give similar, same, or better syntax highlighting, or at least improved graphical representation? IDK, but it's the clear starting point. So, only with that information answered would this become a useful reference as separate from the other two mentioned above.